# Download sqlite database from Heroku

Tags: python, git, sqlite, heroku

I have a worker running python script every 2 hour on Heroku.

The problem is each time I 'pull' the changes from git.

There is no changes at all for the **sqlite3** database.

But I am sure the program is running and the database has changed by looking at the log file.

```
heroku log
```

How to retrieve the .db file then ?

Comment: Hey, can you tell us what solution you found? We have a django website hosted on heroku and adding data on that website changes the db of heroku but it cannot be pulled from there.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal I was long time before I used Heroku, but the answer down below seems validate in the end. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have a little misconception. Heroku's git support is effectively one-way; you can use it to push new code to be run on the server, but you can't use it to copy files from Heroku back to your local tree.

Unfortunately it looks like there's not a good easy way to copy a file from your app to your local machine; you can use `heroku run console` to get a `bash` shell, and then `scp` a file out, but you're "pushing" it out of Heroku, and thus run can only copy to things with valid IP addresses.

If you're really using sqlite for your app's storage, though, you're going to run into a bigger problem. The filesystem for your app on Heroku is ephemeral, in that changes you make can be wiped out at any time. Heroku will delete your app's local storage and start over fresh whenever it wants to.

The right way to do it is use Heroku's built-in Postgres support and store your application's data there. Not only will it persist, but you'll be able to access it directly using the Postgres command-line tools.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the heroku console can now be done with:

`heroku run bash`

then i downloaded the linux gdrive application and ran in locally in the folder to upload my file to google drive. https://olivermarshall.net/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-drive-from-the-command-line/ (skip step 4 and run with `./` like this `./gdrive upload my_file.txt`

the other suggestion of `heroku run console` did not work for me (running a python flask app)